# Using PHP, Need to create MySQL Function on Server

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

This may seem obvious to some, but I am not seeing it, cannot figure how to make this work using PHP, but I don't have direct access to the database on the webserver I am using, and I want to be able to create a function on the server. The code I need to create is below (this is something I've gotten from another post here on Stack Overflow and to the best of my understanding should work), but when I put the code to create the function into a SQL statement and attempt to run it, it errors out on me. Is there a better way?

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnStripTags( Dirty varchar(4000) )
       RETURNS varchar(4000)
       DETERMINISTIC 
       BEGIN
       DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength int;
       WHILE Locate( '<', Dirty ) > 0 And Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate( '<', Dirty )) > 0 DO
         BEGIN
         SET iStart = Locate( '<', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate('<', Dirty ));
         SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 1;
         IF iLength > 0 THEN
            BEGIN
               SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
            END;
         END IF;
         END;
      END WHILE;
      RETURN Dirty;
   END;
   |
   DELIMITER ;
```

The PHP attempt to make it work looks like this:

```
 $sql = "DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fnStripTags";
 $result = mysqli_query( $connect, $sql );
 if( ! $result )
 {
     echo "<p><b>Error in SQL statement ...</b><br />";
     $errornum = mysqli_errno( $connect );
     echo "MySQL Error Number: " . $errornum . "<br />";
     echo "MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error( $connect ) . "<br />";
     echo "SQL Statement: " . $sql . "</p>";
     die;
  }

  $sql = "DELIMITER |
          CREATE FUNCTION fnStripTags( Dirty varchar(4000) )
           RETURNS varchar(4000)
           DETERMINISTIC 
           BEGIN
             DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength int;
               WHILE Locate( '<', Dirty ) > 0 And Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate( '<', Dirty )) > 0 DO
                 BEGIN
                  SET iStart = Locate( '<', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate('<', Dirty ));
                  SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 1;
                  IF iLength > 0 THEN
                     BEGIN
                      SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
                    END;
                  END IF;
                END;
              END WHILE;
              RETURN Dirty;
          END;
          |
          DELIMITER ;";
 $result = mysqli_query( $connect, $sql );
 if( ! $result )
 {
    echo "<p><b>Error in SQL statement ...</b><br />";
    $errornum = mysqli_errno( $connect );
    echo "MySQL Error Number: " . $errornum . "<br />";
    echo "MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error( $connect ) . "<br />";
    echo "SQL Statement: " . $sql . "</p>";
    die;
  }
```

The error returned is:

```
Error in SQL statement ...
MySQL Error Number: 1064
MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER | CREATE FUNCTION fnStripTags( Dirty varchar(4000) ' at line 1
```

The error occurs on the 'create function' command, not the first "drop function". Thanks for any useful suggestions here.

Comment: "Errors out" means what, exactly? Please, supply the *exact* error text in the body of your question so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: Do you happen to have a code snippet of the php part of this question?

Comment: I will add it to the above ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was the use of the delimiter parts of the code shown. I changed the SQL statement being sent to the server to this:

```
$sql = "CREATE FUNCTION fnStripTags( Dirty varchar(4000) )
              RETURNS varchar(4000)
              DETERMINISTIC 
              BEGIN
                DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength int;
                  WHILE Locate( '<', Dirty ) > 0 And Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate( '<', Dirty )) > 0 DO
                    BEGIN
                      SET iStart = Locate( '<', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate('<', Dirty ));
                      SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 1;
                      IF iLength > 0 THEN
                        BEGIN
                          SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
                        END;
                      END IF;
                    END;
                  END WHILE;
                  RETURN Dirty;
              END;";
```

And it successfully tested on my local machine, I will be testing on the server shortly.